# Java - generic type parameter to depend generic interface

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make this compile:

```
package main;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class Example {

public <I extends BaseInterface, T extends BaseClass & I> Iterator<I> getInterfaceIterator(Iterator<T> iterator) {
    return new Iterator<I>() {
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iterator.hasNext();
        }

        public I next() {
            T element = iterator.next();
            return func(element);
        }

        public void remove() {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    };
}

    private <T extends BaseClass> T func(T element) {
        return element;
    }

    public static class BaseClass implements BaseInterface {

    }

    public static interface BaseInterface {

    }

    public static class ImplementingClass extends BaseClass implements ImplementingInterface {

    }

    public static interface ImplementingInterface extends BaseInterface {

    }
}
```

However, I am getting this compilation error:

Error:(7, 60) java: unexpected type
  required: class
  found:    type parameter I

Error:(15, 28) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible upper bounds I,com.stampli.server.commons.communication.Example.BaseClass

Comment: When using an additional bound, like in `A & B`, B needs to be an interface. In your case you are using a generic type `I`. See [JLS 4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4).

Comment: `<I extends BaseInterface, T extends BaseClass & I>` is invalid because `I` could be any type that extends `BaseInterface` including abstract and non-abstract classes while an interface is expected.

Comment: Is there another way than to wrap the original Iterator with the new iterator, as I tried to do?